# Редирект на страницу после авторизации

Tags: django

Здравствуйте. Как отдать страницу после авторизации, чтобы она не была доступна по прямой ссылке? Сейчас, если ввести адрес напрямую, то страница открывается.
urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', UserFormView.as_view(), name='Login'),
url(r'^home/$', home, name='Главная'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.views.generic.edit import View
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import (
authenticate,
login,
)

from .forms import UserLoginForm

class UserFormView(View):
    form = UserLoginForm
    template = 'form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form(None)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        return HttpResponse('<h1>Неверный логин или пароль</h1>')


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(('work_bot.html', {'user':      
    request.user}))
```

forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= .   
{'placeholder': 'Имя пользователя'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
{'placeholder': 'Пароль'}))

class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ['username', 'password']
```

Спасибо! И всех с прошедшим Новым Годом! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Прописал в SETTINGS:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/work_bot/'
```

Во views:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    print(request.user.username)
    return render_to_response(('work_bot.html', {'user':     
    request.user.username}))
```

urls:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^work_bot/', home, name='Главная'),
url(r'^login/', login, {'template_name': 'form.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

Все работает.